Custom Rendering for different publishing targets when triggered in Workflow
We have multiple publishing targets part of workflow. Content will be published to each target when the activity instance is started. We want to capture the rendered data in the first activity instance specific to a publish target (Store temporarily in Cache or DB).
Reuse the data and publish the data for the next upcoming activity/state when invoked and related publish targets rather than performing the same rendering multiple times for each activity/state and publish targets.
Data should be deleted upon completion of the workflow.
Basicaly we do not want to repeat rendering logic multiple times for pages with huge content and want to save time on publishing.

What is the question, exactly?

We have around 4-5 publishing targets, each target is linked to an activity in workflow. So the publishing takes place for 1 target at a time as the workflow progresses the same bundle is published to different targets. Some pages both resolving and rendering takes really long time for 1 target. Want a solution to save the data temporarily when publishing for 1st target post rendering/resolving and when publishing begins for the other targets, we want to get the saved data and publish to target. We want to avoid resolving and rendering for the same bundle multiple times.

I don't think this is possible.
